# reflect progress of slide transition on progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

the transition of the progressbar of `swiperjs`: https://swiperjs.com doesn't reflect the actual progress until it changes to the other slide.

I want it to show it like Facebook and Instagram stories do on autoplay:
[image]

I tried by adding the `watchSlidesProgress: true,` parameter as pointed in the documentation but is not listening the event.

Any help on how to do it?

This is the example web: http://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/progressbar-animation/

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
    paginationClickable: true,
    nested: true,
    watchSlidesProgress: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 2500,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    speed: 500,
    simulateTouch: false,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      type: "progressbar"
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  });
  var swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-v', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    nested: true,
    freeMode: true,
    mousewheel: true,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination-v',
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It looks fine to me.

Comment: @VasilisG. I want the `progress` of the `progressbar` to match the exact time of slide, not change in a millisecond when the slide changes, have you seen how instagram or Facebook stories do it?

Comment: check out this [pen](https://codepen.io/thegamehasnoname/pen/JewZrm). It's not using Swiper.js but you may be able to integrate it.

Comment: @Yasmin thanks, I'll check how to integrate it